# MSE of the Phase Estimation of a Noisy Complex Quantity

Tags: statistics, fourier-analysis, angle

### Presentation of the Problem

I am making a measurement which yields me the complex quantity:

\begin{equation}
 S_k = e^{i \cdot \phi} + X_k + i \cdot Y_k \quad \text{with} \quad X_k, Y_k \stackrel{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma_c^2\right)
\end{equation}

which is affected by a bivariate, independent, Gaussian noise. My **main objective here is to compute the MSE that may be reached on the estimate of $\varphi$** - let us call it $\theta$ - as a function of $\sigma_c$. This MSE is defined as:

\begin{equation}
    MSE = \mathbf{E}\left((\varphi - \theta)^2\right)
\end{equation}

Each ${S_k}$ can be seen as a point in the complex plane of coordinates:

\begin{equation}\label{eq:xy_distri}
 \begin{cases}
  x = \Re{\left({S_k}\right)} = cos\ \varphi + X_k \sim \mathcal{N}(cos \varphi, \sigma_c^2)\\
  y = \Im{\left({S_k}\right)} = sin\ \varphi + Y_k \sim \mathcal{N}(sin \varphi, \sigma_c^2)
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

And we can write $f(x,y)$ as the bivariate normal distribution:

\begin{equation}
 f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \cdot \pi \cdot \sigma_c^2} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2 \cdot \sigma_c^2}\cdot ((x - cos \varphi)^2+(y-sin \varphi)^2)}
\end{equation}

We can use polar coordinate as:

\begin{equation}
 g_\varphi(\theta) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(\theta, r) rdr  \quad \text{with} \quad \begin{cases}
  x = r \cdot cos\ \theta\\
  y = r \cdot sin\ \theta
 \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Yielding ultimately to:

\begin{equation}
 \boxed{
  g(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\cdot \pi} \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma_c^2}} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot \sqrt{2 \cdot \pi} \cdot  \sigma_c} \cdot cos(\theta-\varphi) \cdot e^{-\frac{sin^2(\theta - \varphi)}{2\cdot \sigma_c^2}} \cdot erfc\left(-\frac{cos(\theta - \varphi)}{\sigma_c \cdot \sqrt{2}}\right)
 }
\end{equation}

I checked the latter equation in simulations as can be seen in the Figure below:

[image]

Wherein the blue histogram is a simulation of many ($\sim 10^7$) $S_k$ from which the angle was retrieved.

### Question

**Given the afore-mentioned $g(\theta)$, how can I compute the MSE on $\theta$ with respect to $\varphi$ estimation?** I think that the usual expected value and variance formulae do not apply here given the "circular" nature of $\theta$ *i.e.* the fact that the $\left[0;2\cdot\pi\right]$ folds on itself.

*I would greatly appreciate some help on this issue, even only as keywords or tracks to follow. Do not hesitate if you think that further details are requested either. I tried to keep it short and did not develop all the calculations here, but I may provide additional details upon request.*

Comment: You don't mention the (complex) log of your function whose imaginary part (up to a $k2\pi$ additive constant) provides the phase...

Comment: @JeanMarie, could you please elaborate? I guess you are meaning $log(S_k) = log(e^{i\cdot \varphi} + X_k + Y_k)$, which indeed equals $\varphi$ in the noiseless case. But I do not see how from the $log$, you get information on the MSE of $\varphi$ in the noisy case... I insist that my aim here is to characterize the distribution (or at least the MSE) of a measured phase $\theta$, not only its estimated value.